# Accessing dc.js and crossfilter with RequireJS

Tags: requirejs, dc.js, crossfilter

I am trying to import dc and cross filter into my environment using require js.

I am using the following code in my js file:

```
    require.config({
    paths: {

       "crossfilter": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.7/crossfilter",
       "d3": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.4.0/d3",
       "dc": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/2.1.0-dev/dc"
    }
}); 
require(['crossfilter','d3','dc'], function(){

    console.log("alert");
    });
```

However i am getting an error in my console.
[image]
On some further probing it seems that the utils.js file is throwing up an error in the first line which is :
[image]

I have not included the utils.js anywhere in my code. I am guessing that it is being auto delivered from the cdn.

if i call the requireJS dependenices without the dc.js file, the crossfilter and d3 dont throw an error when i load my page.
What could i possibly be missing?

**EDIT:**
I backported to d3 v3.5 and this problem got solved. 
Now however i am not able to access the dc object when calling the charts. I can see this error in the console. I even added a dependency on d3 while calling the dc Shim but it did not work. Here is my html and JS code. I would have shared a JS Fiddle but not sure if it can be debugged via console.

**HTML CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Require js</title>

        <!-- 1. Add these JavaScript inclusions in the head of your page -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="required.css" />

    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- 3. Add the container -->
        <div id="container" style="width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.2/require.js"></script>

    <script src='required.js' type='text/javascript'></script>  
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS CODE**

```
    require.config({
    paths: {

       "crossfilter": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.5/crossfilter",
       "d3": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3",
       "dc": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/2.1.0-dev/dc"
    },
    shim:{
       'dc':{
         deps:['d3'],
         exports:'dc'
        } 
    }
});

    data = [{
      "name":"anmol",
      "age":"27",
      "salary": "less"
    }]
    require(['crossfilter','d3','dc'], function(){
        console.log(data);
    $(document.body).append('<div id="funding-chart"></div>');
    var ndx = crossfilter(data);
    var fundingStatus = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.funding_status; });
    var projectsByFundingStatus = fundingStatus.group();
    var hutu = fundingStatus.top(Infinity);
    console.log(hutu);
    var fundingStatusChart = dc.pieChart("#funding-chart");
              fundingStatusChart
                .height(220)
                //.width(350)
                .radius(90)
                .innerRadius(40)
                .transitionDuration(1000)
                .dimension(fundingStatus)
                .group(projectsByFundingStatus);
      dc.renderAll();
        });
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems here.

1. Your `require()` callback function needs to receive the libraries you need. This is one of the big selling points of module systems, that the modules don't "pollute" the global namespace. (Of course not every library follows this, but it's the spec and dc.js does follow it.)
2. The version of crossfilter you're using is not AMD-compatible, so it needs to be shimmed. Newer versions of [the community fork of crossfilter](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter) *are* AMD-compatible, but I wasn't able to find it in a CDN (there's an [open issue](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/issues/42))
3. dc.js *is* AMD-compatible, so it does *not* need to be shimmed.

Yes, churn. We love it, that's why we use JavaScript, right? No?

So, the `shim` section should read:

```
shim:{
   'crossfilter':{
     exports:'crossfilter'
    } 
}
```

And the `require()` call should read:

```
require(['crossfilter','d3','dc'], function(crossfilter, d3, dc){
    // ...
```

Here's a working bl.ock:

http://bl.ocks.org/gordonwoodhull/027ab249c86a9370b25eeae5ef5ed2c1

(You're right, I wouldn't trust jsfiddle for testing requireJS stuff. Basic debugging is workable, but this is pretty low-level stuff.)

Finally, if you're willing to pull crossfilter from rawgit.com, you can do away with the shims entirely.

```
   "crossfilter": "https://cdn.rawgit.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/master/crossfilter",
```

http://bl.ocks.org/gordonwoodhull/dfe28f28213c57b53718fe9255ce7cbc

Comment: Worked like a charm!! Thank you for explaining all this. And thank you so much for always being there. #Respect

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Turns out it was an issue with the version of d3 i was using. I ported back to v3.5.3 and it worked.

Comment: Right, dc.js is [not yet compatible with d3v4](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1173).

Comment: @Gordon: I am not able to access the dc object now. Have added more info in the edit. Please take a look when you can. Thanks much!